# mhddfs (or unionfs) + Apache = Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, filesystems, mount, mount-point

currently I am trying to set up a virtual machine for development for a client. Three SVN repositories with PHP code have to be combined in one folder (I know it's ugly, but that's how they roll). I Googled a little and found [mhddfs](http://svn.uvw.ru/mhddfs/trunk/README). So I checked out the three repositories in a folder called `branches`:

```
branches/branch1
branches/branch2
branches/branch3
```

I mounted the three branches with `mhddfs` at `/mnt/dev`. At the filesystem level, everything works as expected, so `ls` correctly displays the contents of all three folders (they are disjoint). However, trying to fire up the document root with Apache results in a **403 Forbidden** error. I tried other locations than `/mnt/dev` as well, leading to no difference.

```
[Mon Feb 06 17:44:41 2012] [error] [client 192.168.56.1]
(13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

When I do not mount the three folders but just put an `index.php` file into `/mnt/dev`, everything works as expected. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: Some more data on the problem: When I create two directories, that are world-accessible ...

```
root@devbox:/tmp > ls -lha
drwxrwxrwt  6 root     root   4,0K  6. Feb 20:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root     root   4,0K  6. Feb 10:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data vboxsf 4,0K  6. Feb 20:11 test1 # includes index.htm
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data vboxsf 4,0K  6. Feb 20:13 test2 # includes index2.htm
```

... and mount them via mhddfs ...

```
mhddfs /tmp/test1,/tmp/test2 /mnt/dev
mhddfs: directory '/tmp/test1' added to list
mhddfs: directory '/tmp/test2' added to list
mhddfs: mount to: /mnt/dev
mhddfs: move size limit 4294967296 bytes
```

... `ls` behaves correctly ...

```
root@devbox:/tmp > ls -lh /mnt/dev/
insgesamt 8,0K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data vboxsf 12  6. Feb 20:11 index2.htm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data vboxsf 11  6. Feb 20:11 index.htm
```

... while Apache (user: `www-data`, group: `vboxsf`) doesn't and terminates with the 403 error stated above. However, if I unmount the folders and just put an `index.htm` in `/mnt/dev`, everything works as expected as Apache can read the file.

Any ideas?

All the best,
Martin

Comment: Does apache have permissions to read the files inside /mnt/dev? Just because the mount point itself is "open" to apache, doesn't mean whatever you're mounting inside is as well.

Comment: Yes. I am running Apache with user:group www-data:vboxsf (since I want to access the files in the shared folder of VirtualBox). I even tried to set the permissions to 0777 for debugging purposes, but no success. I will shortly provide some more data.

Comment: I appended some more information in the topic.

Comment: Nobody? Otherwise I will just use *rsync* and replicate all folders to one upon change/touch. Stupid, but a working solution (and deserved for this degenerated SVN structure) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on Linux.
Following the steps below, I was able to solve it.

**`[STEPS]`**

1. Enable 'user_allow_other' in /etc/fuse.conf
2. Use mhddfs with '-o allow_other' option
    ex. mhddfs -o allow_other
       /dir1,/dir2 /path/to/mount